# What is the branch name variable for Jenkins multibranch pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I need to know which branch is being built in my Jenkins multibranch pipeline in order for it to run steps correctly.

We are using a gitflow pattern with `dev`, `release`, and `master` branches that all are used to create artifacts. The `dev` branch auto deploys, the other two do not. Also there are `feature`, `bugfix` and `hotfix` branches. These branches should be built, but not produce an artifact. They should just be used to inform the developer if there is a problem with their code.

In a standard build, I have access to the `$GIT_BRANCH` variable to know which branch is being built, but that variable isn't set in my multibranch pipeline. I have tried `env.GIT_BRANCH` too, and I tried to pass `$GIT_BRANCH` as a parameter to the build. Nothing seems to work. I assumed that since the build knows about the branch being built (I can see the branch name at the top of the console output) that there is something that I can use - I just can't find any reference to it.

Comment: Could you please update the correct answer now that it has been resolved for people who come here via search?

Comment: NB: In declarative pipelines, you probably want to use [`when`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) to control which stages are executed on which branches/tags.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The `env.BRANCH_NAME` variable contains the branch name.

As of [Pipeline Groovy Plugin 2.18](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Groovy+Plugin), you can also just use `BRANCH_NAME`
 (`env` isn't required but still accepted.)

Comment: Couldn't get this to work at all in a script {} block at the top of the steps {} block. By printing the env using echo env.getEnvironment() I found that ${env.BRANCH} is available and that works!

Comment: Interesting, none of these work for me. Dumped everything under env - there was neither BRANCH nor BRANCH_NAME. When I tried to refer to BRANCH_NAME I get "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BRANCH_NAME for class: groovy.lang.Binding"

Pipeline Groovy: 2.32, Jenkins 2.32, BitBucket 4.6.2, BitBucket Server Webhook for Jenkins 3.0.1

Comment: Bizarrely, I find that this works on certain repositories and not others. I have two multi-branch pipelines set up with the same line in their jenkinsfiles: `if(env.BRANCH_NAME == "master")` and it works as expected in one, in the other produces `RejectedAccessException: unclassified field java.lang.String BRANCH_NAME`. Very strange.

Comment: @Vroomfundel if you were executing a Pipeline job that is not a multibranch Pipeline job, that is (apparently) the expected condition, due to [JENKINS-47226](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47226) - Branch name not available in single Pipeline build.

Comment: In my opinion its CHANGE_BRANCH at least for PullRequest

Answer (score 11):

<strike>There is not a dedicated variable for this purpose yet ([JENKINS-30252](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30252)). In the meantime you can take advantage of the fact that the subproject name is taken from the branch name, and use</strike>

```
env.JOB_NAME.replaceFirst('.+/', '')
```

This has now been resolved, see [Krzysztof Krasoń's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37085196/383124).

Comment: Thanks, that got me pointed in the right direction. Here is a little more information that helped me to get what I needed. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30252 is an issue logged against the workflow plugin for this exact thing. @jesse-glick answered in more detail there. To summarize: ${env.JOB_NAME.replaceFirst('.+/', '')} will give you the branch name.

Comment: Thanks, incorporated into answer.

Comment: Also, making it non-greedy might be helpful for those who put slashes in their branch names. env.JOB_NAME.replaceFirst('.+?/', '')

Comment: No, because that will break inside folders. How branches with `/` in their names actually get handled is a good question—this is not currently tested, and might not work. Probably the slash needs to be URL-encoded in the job name or something like this.

Comment: [JENKINS-30744](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30744) for more on that.

Comment: You can now use `${env.BRANCH_NAME}` (as [JENKINS-30252](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30252) has been resolved)

Comment: Or simply `$BRANCH_NAME` in sufficiently new versions of `workflow-cps`.

Comment: Thank you! This is fixed my URL bar issue. Now i can go to full URL: `PIPELINE_URL        =   "${env.JENKINS_URL}/job/${PIPELINE_NAME}/job/${env.BRANCH_NAME.replaceFirst('/', '%2F')}"`

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 branches to consider in a Jenkins multibranch pipeline job:

1. The Jenkins job branch - `env.BRANCH_NAME`. This may have the same name as a git branch, but might also be called PR-123 or similar
2. The git branch - `env.GIT_BRANCH`. This is the actual branch name in git.

So a job might have BRANCH_NAME=PR-123 and GIT_BRANCH=my-scm-branch-name

Comment: I am not sure what's so different in our Jenkins setup but in our case also GIT_BRANCH is PR-123.

Comment: You can find all the env vars configured for your Jenkins instance's at https://your-jenkins-server.example.com/env-vars.html

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins documentation has a list of all the env variable for your perusal [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using the `git` command to obtain the branch name on the current jenkins pipeline. For example, you can add the following snippet to print the branch name in your `Jenkinsfile`.

```
...
script {
    def BRANCH = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()
    echo ${BRANCH}
}
...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you maybe edit your answer to clarify, where this method (which comes with additional overhead) has its advantage over the built-in, ready-to-use variable as described in the accepted answer?

Comment: Note that this only works after the repository has already been cloned and checked out successfully. It will not work before that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this stackoverflow post example useful: [Git Variables in Jenkins Workflow plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554983/git-variables-in-jenkins-workflow-plugin)

```
sh '//...
    git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD > GIT_BRANCH'
    git_branch = readFile('GIT_BRANCH').trim()
    echo git_branch
    //...
   '
```