# Git Variables in Jenkins Workflow plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to access git variables such as `GIT_COMMIT` and `GIT_BRANCH` when I have checked out a repository from git further down in the build stream. Currently I find no available variable to access these two parameters.

```
node {
    git git+ssh://git.com/myproject.git
    echo "$GIT_COMMIT - $BRANCH_NAME"
}
```

Is such variables available and in case, where would I find them. I don't mind if they are available through some groovy variables or wherever, just that I can access them.

Maybe I lack the debugging skills in Groovy and this is easy to find, but I just can't find it with my limited skills.

Comment: I have tried casting git to a variable, but it seems to return null. def gitInfo = git git+ssh://git.com/myproject.git

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing currently. Would be pretty helpful to figure this one out.

Comment: I have the exact same problem in my script where I'd like to use GIT_URL and GIT_BRANCH env variables (that should be populated in GitSCM if I'm not mistaken). In my case I use a "Pipeline script from SCM" and would like to get those variables in my Git-commited Groovy script.
Moreover the mentionned hack does not work in my case because the head is detached from master (or any branch) once the SCM polling has happened... any solution ?

Comment: Is there a reason that these aren't available?

Comment: Awaiting resolution of  [JENKINS-35230 The environment variables of git plugin not working in pipeline script](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35230)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I good way to fix this for now is to use the Multi-branch pipeline, and it might be good to know that Bitbucket and Github have plugins in Jenkins that sets up an organisation and autodiscovers new projects. This works natively then with env.GIT_BRANCH

For commit ID I would suggest what @mkobit wrote above.

Comment: Any suggestion for `GIT_URL`? I have not been able to find a work around for that

Comment: None yet I'm afraid, I'd like to see the previous variables implemented as they were, however at the point I was looking into this there were some problem with the git plugin for Jenkins blocking this, maybe that has been updated.

Answer (score 49):

Depending on the SCM plugin you are using, the `checkout` step may return additional information about the revision. This was resolved in [JENKINS-26100](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26100). It was released in the [2.6 version of the `workflow-scm-step` plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+SCM+Step+Plugin).

For example, using the Git plugin, you can do something like:

```
final scmVars = checkout(scm)
echo "scmVars: ${scmVars}"
echo "scmVars.GIT_COMMIT: ${scmVars.GIT_COMMIT}"
echo "scmVars.GIT_BRANCH: ${scmVars.GIT_BRANCH}"
```

This will vary depending on the plugin you use, so the original answer may work better for you.

---

**Original Answer**

With the 2.4 release of the [*Pipeline Nodes and Processes Plugin*](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Nodes+and+Processes+Plugin), you can simply do:

```
def gitCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
```

Comment: and there's a `--short` flag for `rev-parse` to get the first 7 characters

Comment: Make sure to include the `trim()` always

Answer (score 13):

Depending on the information you need, there is a very straightforward solution: get the "checkout scm" operation return: it provides GIT_BRANCH, GIT_COMMIT, GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT, GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT and GIT_URL.

```
node { 
    stage ("Checkout") {

        scmInfo = checkout scm

        /*...*/
        echo "scm : ${scmInfo}"
        echo "${scmInfo.GIT_COMMIT}"


    }
}
```

This will output:

```
...
[Pipeline] echo
    scm : [GIT_BRANCH:my-branch, GIT_COMMIT:0123456789abcdefabcdef0123456789abcdef01, GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT:aaaabbbcccdddeeeefffe0123456789012345678, GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT:aaaabbbcccdddeeeefffe0123456789012345678, GIT_URL:http://my.si.te/my-repository.git]
[Pipeline] echo
    0123456789abcdefabcdef0123456789abcdef01
...
```

More details here [Jenkins Pipeline SCM Steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/)

Answer (score 11):

This is what I'm doing, based on the [example provided in the Jenkins examples repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/gitcommit/gitcommit.groovy):

```
node {
    git url: 'https://git.com/myproject.git'

    sh 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD > GIT_BRANCH'
    git_branch = readFile('GIT_BRANCH').trim()
    echo git_branch

    sh 'git rev-parse HEAD > GIT_COMMIT'
    git_commit = readFile('GIT_COMMIT').trim()
    echo git_commit
}
```

**Edit** you can do this shorter via

```
git_commit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse HEAD").trim()
```

Comment: When I do the first one I get GIT_BRANCH=HEAD

Answer (score 1):

This example might get you further:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/tree/master/pipeline-examples/gitcommit

In this example they are piping the output of git commands to a file, and then reading the file.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't cover branch name. It is a hacky way around one of the problems. Branch name is important when working with Git Flow etc, or if you want to continuously integrate various branches.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your jobs (extracting git info from last commit) inside `node` for execution in a queue.

```
node {

  //Code checkout from SCM (here - `git`)
  checkout scm

  stage("GIT INFO"){
    echo ":::::::::::GIT_SHORT_COMMIT::::::::::::::::::::::::"

    GIT_SHORT_COMMIT = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%h'").trim()
    //echo in jenkins console
    echo GIT_SHORT_COMMIT
    //wanted to send these info to build artifacts, append to any file
    sh("echo ${GIT_SHORT_COMMIT} > GIT_SHORT_COMMIT")

    //Similar proceed for other git info's 
    echo ":::::::::::GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL::::::::::::::::::::::::"

    GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git show -s --pretty=%ae").trim()
    sh("echo ${GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL} > GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL-${GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL}")



    echo ":::::::::::GIT_COMMITTER_NAME::::::::::::::::::::::::"

    GIT_COMMITTER_NAME = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git show -s --pretty=%an").trim()
    sh("echo ${GIT_COMMITTER_NAME} > GIT_COMMITTER_NAME-${GIT_COMMITTER_NAME}")
  }
```

After your job is finished, you will see three additional file from above task in your workspace :

`.
|-- GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL_email@gmail.com
|-- GIT_COMMITTER_NAME-username
|-- GIT_SHORT_COMMIT_<commit-short-ID-ef9e91c>`

Answer (score 1):

Additional information:
If you are using agent, like docker in pipeline, the agent SHOULD have git installed inside of container. Without git it won't add variables like "GIT_COMMIT, GIT_BRANCH, GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL ... etc"

In case there is no installed git inside the container, you can use a Jenkins git plugin to make a checkout and interact with git variables, like this:

```
stage ('Clone') {
  steps {
    script {
      def scmVars = checkout BbS(branches: [[name: '*/develop']], credentialsId: 'bitbucket-jenkins', extensions: [], gitTool: 'default-git', id: '436fd534-c616-4a81-94d9-f67f32c03c1c', projectName: 'intuence-discovery-analysis-configuration', repositoryName: 'api-gateway-elasticsearch-proxy', serverId: 'b4943a46-b885-4aa3-90be-033e40460794')
      echo "scmVars.GIT_COMMIT"
      echo "${scmVars.GIT_COMMIT}"
      env.GIT_COMMIT = scmVars.GIT_COMMIT
      sh "printenv"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest way to fetch the Git variable in Jenkins through Jenkinsfile**

```
node {
  def scmVars = checkout scm
  echo 'scm : the commit id is ' +scmVars.GIT_COMMIT
  echo 'scm : the commit branch  is ' +scmVars.GIT_BRANCH
  echo 'scm : the previous commit id is ' +scmVars.GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT
  def commitEmail = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git --no-pager show -sformat=\'%ae\'")
  echo " the commiter email is'${commitEmail}'"
  def commitName = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git --no-pager show -s format=\'%an\'")
  echo " the commiter name is'${commitName}'"
}
```

In console you will get the

```
GIT_COMMIT:
GIT_BRANCH:
GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT:
commitEmail:
commitName:
```