# SHA Commit number from Pipelinec w/ Openshift Plugin

Tags: openshift, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using the [`OpenShift plugin`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/openshift-pipeline-plugin) with `Jenkins Pipelines` to run builds in OpenShift when Github gets a new commit.

I'd also like to be able to report the status of the build back to github.

However in order to do this, I need to know what the commit was that just got built. I'm using the following pipeline config

```
node() {

   stage 'build'
   def builder = openshiftBuild(buildConfig: 'my-web', showBuildLogs: 'true')

   stage 'deploy'
   openshiftDeploy(deploymentConfig: 'my-web')
   openshiftScale(deploymentConfig: 'my-web',replicaCount: '3')    

}
```

However I have zero idea how to get the commit SHA from the openshiftBuild step since this does the git pull.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554983/git-variables-in-jenkins-workflow-plugin

Comment: Afraid not :( since the git pull happens within the openshift build the variable doesn't appear to be accessible at this point.

Comment: Can you try `builder.getCommitID()` from the plugin code its seems that should have the commit id?

Comment: If the above does not work do you have access to the oc binary?

Comment: it doesn't appear to work since as soon as the builder is complete the object is nullified. So I get a null reference. I do have access to OC but since the pipeline is within Openshift itself I'm not sure we can call the OC command from inside.

Comment: @JohnMitchell, In groovy an object cannot be just nullified if you have a reference to it, unless it's a week reference (not your case).

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko when I echo out the `builder` I just get `null`. It could be that the `openshiftBuild` step just never sets anything or I'm inspecting it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables, you get it from the `GIT_COMMIT` environment variable.

If the checkout happens later, you can get it with the following code:

```
def gitCommitId = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD')
```

Comment: Since the open-shift builder seems to be self contained, git rev-parse doesn't' appear to be in existence.Also tried echoing out all env's and the GIT_COMMIT isn't there (either before or after the builder runs).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of your pipeline, but it looks like you are just triggering an OpenShift S2I build, which is not what is recommended for Pipeline builds. You should have your pipeline build the artifact(s) for the application, then use an S2I binary build to have OpenShift put the artifacts into a runtime container. For an example, see [HERE](https://github.com/redhat-cop/container-pipelines/blob/master/basic-spring-boot/Jenkinsfile).