# Pass git information to a downstream build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to pass the git change set information that is checked out of a multi-branch pipeline job to a downstream job that runs the test of this build and sends an email to committers if the build is broken after the test, is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What’s a “downstream job”?

Comment: @evolutionxbox A downstream job is one built by the first pipeline job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Variables in Jenkins Workflow plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554983/git-variables-in-jenkins-workflow-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

This has been answer here: [Git Variables in Jenkins Workflow plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554983/git-variables-in-jenkins-workflow-plugin)

After you have the Git variables you can just pass them as standard parameters between jobs.

--- Update ---

An example build call might be:

```
build job: 'Trial_Test_Pipe',
      parameters: [string(name: 'GIT_BRANCH', value: ${GIT_BRANCH}),
                   string(name: 'GIT_COMMIT', value: ${GIT_COMMIT}),
                   string(name: 'GIT_COMMITTER_NAME', value: ${GIT_COMMITTER_NAME)]
```

Comment: When you say pass them as standard parameters do you mean string? How do I pass it to a job I call with "build job"

Comment: Hi @zstring, yes you could pass them as string parameters from the upstream to the downstream job