# Pull the current branch with Jenkins workflow multibranch plugin

Tags: java, git, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I have set up Jenkins and I am using the Jenkins workflow multibranch plugin. I have configured it to listen for commits in a GitHub repo for any branch.

This is a sample of the `Jenkinsfile` committed in one of the branches:

```
node {
   // Mark the code checkout 'stage'....
   stage 'Checkout'

   // Get some code from a GitHub repository
   git url: 'git@github.com:Me/my-repo.git', credentialsId: '###'

   // Get the maven tool.
   // ** NOTE: This 'M3' maven tool must be configured
   // **       in the global configuration.
   def mvnHome = tool 'M3'

   stage 'Build'
   sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean install"
}
```

When I commit something in this branch a build is triggered. The problem is that git checkouts the master branch and not the branch that is building at the moment.

How can I checkout the branch for the current build?

---

**The solutions so far**

1. Use `checkout scm` instead of `git url: 'git@github.com:Me/my-repo.git', credentialsId: '###'` This way you will checkout the current branch.
2. Use the branch variable - check this for more info: [Jenkins Multibranch pipeline: What is the branch name variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789619/jenkins-multibranch-workflow-what-is-the-branch-name-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Jenkinsfile`, add the name of the branch to checkout with the `branch` parameter on the `git` line:

```
git {...}, branch: 'branch-name'
```

Some build triggers set an environment variable that contains the branch name (e.g., [Gerrit Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger#GerritTrigger-UsagewiththeGitPlugin) sets `GERRIT_BRANCH`), which would allow you to set `branch` to that environment variable instead of hard-coding per branch.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found out that I can use `checkout scm` instead of the `git` command. It checkouts the current branch.

Comment: Oh, that's way better than my answer.