# Get github webhook info from pipeline script in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to get github webhook info from jenkins pipeline script? 
For example, i want to know branch name and repo url. And further it will be used in cloning github repository to local machine:

```
git credentialsId: 'xxx', url: 'xxx', branch: 'xxx'
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you configured your Github webhook ? Are you using Github organization plugin, or you only using a pure Github webhook triggering a Jenkins job... ?

Comment: My job is triggered, so I receive payload. I use simple Github webhook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by printing out the env variables that are available to the job by:

```
echo "env:  ${env.getEnvironment()}"
```

and see what is available.

I'm using Github and seeing:

```
BRANCH, BRANCH_NAME, CHANGE_AUTHOR, CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME, CHANGE_BRANCH, CHANGE_ID, CHANGE_TARGET, CHANGE_TITLE, CHANGE_URL...
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the better way to do what you want is to use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin. By using this plugin and this answer - [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32808188/5790043)  - you can find the branch name.

Comment: I don't need the same Jenkinsfile in each repo. The question about pipeline plugin.