# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline - Dynamic Environment Variable Based On Git Branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have a multi-branch Jenkins pipeline which is working fine. Now, I'm trying to optimize it. I have the following step:

`

```
stage('Migration-Dev') {
      environment {
        ENVIRONMENT = 'development'
      }
      when {
        anyOf {
          branch 'development';
          branch 'staging';          
          branch 'production';
         }
      }

      steps {
        echo "Installing the NodeJS dependencies..."
        sh 'npm ci'
        echo "Performing some more tasks"
        sh 'do somethingelse
       }
       }
```

`

Every git branch mentioned in the above step requires its unique `ENVIRONMENT` value to execute some specific actions.

Is it possible to dynamically create the `ENVIRONMENT` value name depending on the git branch instead of hard coding it? Something like if the branch is `staging`, then the `ENVIRONMENT=release`?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789619/what-is-the-branch-name-variable-for-jenkins-multibranch-pipelines)

What I have for example in my pipeline:

```
    environment {
        APIGEE_ORGANIZATION = "companyName"
        }

    stages {

        stage('Setup') {
                steps {
                    echo 'Getting Proxies source from Gitea'

                    script
                        {
                                if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'qas') {
                                    echo 'Deployment to qas'
                                    env.APIGEE_ENVIRONMENT = 'qas'
                                }
                                if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'sandbox'){
                                    env.APIGEE_ENVIRONMENT = 'sandbox'
                                    echo 'Deployment to sandbox'
                                }
                                if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'main'){
                                    env.APIGEE_ENVIRONMENT = 'prod'
                                    echo 'Deployment to prod'
                                }
                         }
```